# Getting TemplateDoesNotExist at /

Tags: python, django, chatterbot

Im getting error

> TemplateDoesNotExist at /AI.html

I tried to look for the problem but i cant find it.

> Request Method:   GET
>   Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
>   Django Version: 3.0.4
>   Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist
>   Exception Value:
>   AI.html
>   Exception Location: C:\Users\Davids dator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py in get_template, line 19
>   Python Executable:  C:\Users\Davids dator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe
>   Python Version: 3.7.6
>   Python Path:
>   ['C:\Users\Davids dator\Desktop\templateee\Mysite',
>    'C:\Users\Davids '
>    'dator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python37.zip',
>    'C:\Users\Davids dator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\DLLs',
>    'C:\Users\Davids dator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib',
>    'C:\Users\Davids dator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37',
>    'C:\Users\Davids dator\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages',
>    'C:\Users\Davids '
>    'dator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages']

Traceback

> Environment:
>
> Request Method: GET Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/
>
> Django Version: 3.0.4 Python Version: 3.7.6 Installed Applications:
>   ['django.contrib.admin',  'django.contrib.auth', 
>   'django.contrib.contenttypes',  'django.contrib.sessions', 
>   'django.contrib.messages',  'django.contrib.staticfiles',  'MyApp']
>   Installed Middleware:
>   ['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware', 
>   'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware', 
>   'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware', 
>   'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware', 
>   'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware', 
>   'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware', 
>   'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']
>
> Template loader postmortem Django tried loading these templates, in
>   this order:
>
> Using engine django:
>       * django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\Users\Davids dator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templates\AI.html
>   (Source does not exist)
>       * django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\Users\Davids dator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\templates\AI.html
>   (Source does not exist)
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\Davids
>   dator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py",
>   line 34, in inner
>       response = get_response(request)   File "C:\Users\Davids dator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py",
>   line 115, in _get_response
>       response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)   File "C:\Users\Davids
>   dator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py",
>   line 113, in _get_response
>       response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)   File "C:\Users\Davids dator\Desktop\templateee\Mysite\MyApp\views.py", line 36, in Index
>       return render(request, "AI.html", {'form': context})   File "C:\Users\Davids
>   dator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py",
>   line 19, in render
>       content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)   File "C:\Users\Davids
>   dator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py",
>   line 61, in render_to_string
>       template = get_template(template_name, using=using)   File "C:\Users\Davids
>   dator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py",
>   line 19, in get_template
>       raise TemplateDoesNotExist(template_name, chain=chain)
>
> Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist at / Exception Value: AI.html

Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
import json
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

from chatterbot import ChatBot

# Create your views here.
chatbot = ChatBot(
    'Ron Obvious',
    trainer='chatterbot.trainers.ChatterBotCorpusTrainer'
)

@csrf_exempt
def get_response(request):
    response = {'status': None}

    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = json.loads(request.body.decode('utf-8'))
        message = data['message']

        chat_response = chatbot.get_response(message).text
        response['message'] = {'text': chat_response, 'user': False, 'chat_bot': True}
        response['status'] = 'ok'

    else:
        response['error'] = 'no post data found'

    return HttpResponse(
        json.dumps(response),
            content_type="application/json"
        )

def Index (request):
    context = {'title': 'Chatbot Version 1.0'}
    return render(request, "AI.html", {'form': context})
```

Settings.py

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

project_root = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

STATIC_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(project_root, 'static'),
)

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.urls import path
from MyApp.views import Index, get_response
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url('', Index),
    path('get-response/', get_response),
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `settings.py` is missing the template directory.

You should add

```py
TEMPLATES = [ { "BACKEND": "django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates", "DIRS": ["/absolute/path/to/your/templates/",], "APP_DIRS": True, "OPTIONS": { "context_processors": [ "django.template.context_processors.debug", "django.template.context_processors.request", "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth", "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages", ], }, }, ]
```

Comment: Thanks for the heads up but I actually already had it. I've updated the settings.py

Comment: Is `'DIRS': [],` an empty list? If so you should add the absolute path to your templates directory.

Comment: Yes it was... Didnt realize this. Thanks! I will try adding it and see if it works better